# Python ElementTree Serialize Error when writing to disk

Tags: xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I parse a file in python

```
tree = ET.parse('existing.xml')
```

Add some xml Elements  in memory into the XML Structure

```
NodeList = tree.findall(".//NodeList")

NodeList_WeWant = buildingNodeList[0]

for member in aList:
    ET.SubElement(NodeList_WeWant,member)
```

Write back to Disk

```
tree.write("output.sbp", encoding="utf-16")
```

But I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runonreal.py", line 156, in <module>
    tree.write("output.sbp", encoding="utf-16")
  File "C:\Python340\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 775, in write
    qnames, namespaces = _namespaces(self._root, default_namespace)
  File "C:\Python340\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 887, in _namespaces
    _raise_serialization_error(tag)
  File "C:\Python340\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1059, in _raise_serialization_error
    "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize <Element 'BuildingNodeBase' at 0x099421B0> (type Element)
```

***Edit. A Simple Replication of Error. See Below***

My basic xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<family>
  <person>
  <id>100</id>
  <name>Shorn</name>
  <height>5.8</height>
  </person>
  <person>
  <id>101</id>
  </person>
</family>
```

Python Script

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from copy import deepcopy

tree = ET.parse('basic.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

cloneFrom = tree.findall(".//person[name='Shorn']")

cloneTo =  tree.findall(".//person[id='101']")

cloneTo = deepcopy(cloneFrom)

ET.SubElement(root,cloneTo)

tree.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-16")
```

This errors out
[image]

And this is my expected output.xml . Person Node should be cloned to another person node and written back to disk.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<family>
  <person>
  <id>100</id>
  <name>Shorn</name>
  <height>5.8</height>
  </person>
  <person>
  <id>100</id>
  <name>Shorn</name>
  <height>5.8</height>
  </person>
</family>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems here:

- `findall()` returns a list, not a single element.
- `SubElement` expects a string, not an `Element` object, as the second argument.
- The element with id='101' is not removed.

Here is code that works for me (tested with Python 3.6.1):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from copy import deepcopy

tree = ET.parse('basic.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

remove = tree.find(".//person[id='101']")
cloneFrom = tree.find(".//person[name='Shorn']")

root.remove(remove)
root.append(deepcopy(cloneFrom))

tree.write("output.xml", encoding="utf-16")
```

This is what output.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>
﻿<family>﻿
  ﻿<person>﻿
    ﻿<id>100</id>﻿
    ﻿<name>Shorn</name>﻿
    ﻿<height>5.8</height>﻿
  ﻿</person>﻿
  ﻿<person>﻿
    ﻿<id>100</id>﻿
    ﻿<name>Shorn</name>﻿
    ﻿<height>5.8</height>﻿
  ﻿</person>﻿
  ﻿</family>
```